# How to stylize the divs of first child having same classes as other child

Tags: html, css

I want to style(*say change width or color*) the div inside first child, using the classes **.child** and **.grandchild**, which are also inside other child divs, but keeping the other child div intact. Here i only able to select the first child only.

```css
 DIV.parent> DIV:first-child.grandchild {background:red;width:70px;}
 
 .grandchild{font-size:10px;width:50px;height:50px;background:yellow;}
 .child{padding:5px;}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>

<div class='child'>
<div class='grandchild'>
FIRST
</div>
</div>

<div class='child'>
<div class='grandchild'>
SECOND
</div>
</div>

<div class='child'>
<div class='grandchild'>
THIRD
</div>
</div>

<div class='child'>
<div class='grandchild'>
FOURTH
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: thank you all for reaching out, but i want to expand the **width** and change **color** of .grandchild only inside first child.

Comment: use this `.child:first-child .grandchild {border:solid 10px #000;background:red;width:30%;height:10%} `

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this ? **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/vad1s6L4/)**

your question it's a bit unclear

code

```
.child:first-child .grandchild {border:solid 10px #000;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.child:first-child > .grandchild{
  width:200px;
  background:#f22;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with nth-child(n) selector. for example:

```
DIV.parent> DIV:nth-child(1) {border:solid 10px #000;}
DIV.parent> DIV:nth-child(2) {border:solid 10px #000;}
```